# ReactJS upload image with yii2 api

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, yii2

I'm trying to upload an image through the react-images-upload package. However, I have no idea what the API handling should look like.

The React code so far:

```
    renderForm() {
        return (
            <section className="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <ImageUploader
                                name='image'
                                withIcon={ true }
                                buttonText='Choose images'
                                onChange={ this.onDrop }
                                imgExtension={ ['.jpg', '.png'] }
                                maxFileSize={ 1048576 }
                                withPreview={ true }
                                label='Max file size: 10mb, accepted: jpg, png'
                                fileSizeError='File is too big.'
                                fileTypeError=': not supported extension.'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <input className="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.createSponsor(this.state);
}

onDrop(picture) {
    this.setState({
        pictures: this.state.pictures.concat(picture)
    });
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        pictures: []
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
}
```

And the Yii2 API code. When I am trying to fill the $model with UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image'), it still remains empty after var_dump-ing.

```
    public function actionCreateSponsor()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;

        if ($request->post()) {
            $model = new Sponsors();
            $model->name = $request->post('name');

            $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

            //var_dump($model); die;

            if (ImageUploadComponent::upload($model)) {
                return Json::encode(['status' => true, 'data' => 'success']);
            } else {
                return Json::encode(['status' => false, 'data' => 'error_not_saved']);
            }
    }
```

Note: the ImageUploadComponent is empty for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    $model->image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');

   //instead of
    $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since youre not using `ActiveForm` and `$model` to generate your form, and your form don't have specific name, you have to get file by:

```
$model->image = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');
```

Comment: When var_dump-ing the $model->image, it only shows NULL. I reckon it has something to do with the request.